# How to populate morris charts from database

Tags: javascript, mysql, morris.js

How can I populate [morris charts](http://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/) using data from `MySQL database`?

I tried calling the PHP file fetching the data but it was not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is just one sample example of how you can do it

```
var dataArray = [];

function fetchData() {
    $.getJSON('data_source_link', function(data) {
        dataArray = data;
    }
    return dataArray;
}

var myMorrisChart = Morris.Line({
    element: 'graph',
    xkey: 'your_x_key',
    ykeys: 'your_y_keys',
    labels: ['Your Labels'],
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
    ...
});

 myMorrisChart.setData(fetchData());
```

For more info take a look at the **[GitHub Link](https://morrisjs.github.io/morris.js/lines.html)**